# Expected Type in Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I implemented a protocol in objective-c and when I use an own class as type definition xCode tells that a type is required.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h"

@protocol LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)camera:(LPRPhotoCaptureCamera *)camera finishedCapturingPhoto:(UIImage *)capturedUIImage;

@end
```

I looked in the header files from Apples Delegates and edited my protocol with a `@class LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` and it works.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h"

@class LPRPhotoCaptureCamera;
@protocol LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)camera:(LPRPhotoCaptureCamera *)camera finishedCapturingPhoto:(UIImage *)capturedUIImage;

@end
```

I wonder why xCode does not throw an error for UIImage here, do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Because `UIImage` is defined in `UIKit` and you did the import: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`. But before hand, `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` wasn't defined "yet".

Comment: You no longer need `#import "LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h"` if you use the forward declaration `@class LPRPhotoCaptureCamera`.

Answer (score 0):

What probably happened (I am guessing because you did not show us the files) is that `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h` imports `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h` at the top of the file. So what you have an import cycle.

So for example, when compiling `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.m`, it will import `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h`, which imports `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h` at the top of the file (before the declaration of the `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` class). `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h` then imports `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h`, but `#import` guarantees that a file is only imported once, so this import doesn't import anything. So when it gets inside the declaration of the `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate` protocol, it refers to the type `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera *`, which it doesn't understand because the `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` hasn't been declared yet.

In other words, although `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h` imports `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h`, that import doesn't actually import `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` because we have already started importing (and are in the middle of) `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h` at a higher level.

The usual way to deal with when types refer to each other in a cycle is to use forward declarations. The declaration of `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate` only uses a pointer to `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera`, so it doesn't actually need the declaration of the `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` class -- it just needs to know that it's a class. A forward declaration like `@class LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` will do, which will allow you to no longer import `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h` in `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h`. Similarly, if the declaration of `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera` only uses `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate` in the type of a variable, e.g. `id<LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate> delegate`, then it doesn't actually need the declaration of `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate` -- it just needs to know that it's a protocol, so a forward declaration like `@protocol LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate` will do, and you don't have to import `LPRPhotoCaptureCameraDelegate.h` in `LPRPhotoCaptureCamera.h`. Usually, the only time you need to import B's header in A's header is if A implements B protocol or inherits from B class.